# Animate RecycleView horizontally, and center its items

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `ListAdapter`.

I dispose my items horizontaly.

I have dynamic data which can add, remove and move.

I would like add some animation. To that end, I put a `ItemAnimator` on my `RecycleView`:

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = new SlideInUpAnimator();
```

I used the this [RecyclerView animators library](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators).

I would like the center the items in my `RecyclerView`. For example, if I have one item, it must be in the center.

For this, I put the `layout_width` with `wrap_content` in my `RecyclerView`. The problem is that the move and delete animations aren't working.

When I put the `layout_width` in `match_parent`, the animations work correctly, but the items are not centered.

I don't understand, then, why `wrap_content` is erasing the animations. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: What a coincidence, this is what I am struggling right now. I can explain this, but cannot give an exact solution. Apparently, you are animating the items in the `RecyclerView`, but not the layout itself. By setting the `layout_width` to `WRAP_CONTENT`, the animations will get dissappear, as the `RecyclerView` doesn't know how to animate it's width to compensate the item animations.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the problem. I try to let the match parent in recycle view. For update my list, I use the submitList. In the runnable parameter of this method, i loop each element of my recycleview and i recalculate the margin:

val p = element.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
if (index == 0)  p.leftMargin = margin else p.leftMargin = 100

with this solution, i see animation but its works very poorly